# Mobiscroll EventCalendar month and years picker disappearing after selecting in ionic react app

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, mobiscroll

I am using EventCalendar from mobiscroll on my Ionic React app, everthing else works fine but here is the problem: it's working when select years back(like 1890) but when I try to select years after current year(like 2040), the Month/years button will just go disappear which I won't be able to see or select anything else, is anyone expirencing this problem before?

[This is what it suppose to look like and while it works normal:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyrUe.png)

[This is what it looks like when the problem comes up:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Riy89.png)

Here is the basic code I have for the EventCalendar:

```
        <Eventcalendar
            theme={"windows"}
            view={view}
            selectedDate={date}
        />
```

Comment: refer this link: https://blog.logrocket.com/react-calendar-tutorial-build-customize-calendar/                           This may be help you

Comment: Thank you for the information, however,I am using Mobiscroll for the calendar.